# python webdriver get each child text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hello first of all I have to say that I am really new in python. I am trying to get text from specific span from each child.

What i am getting now from this code is just text from first element. (from ex. just 3 times blabla1, not blabla1, blabla2, blabla3) What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

structure looks like this(each ssBlock has much more others divs and spans that I havent mentioned):

```
<div id="js-live">
   <div class="ssBlock">
      <div class="ssName">
         <span class="floatL withSvgIcon">
            <div class="row middle-xs">
               <div class="col-xs col-xs-auto">
                  <svg class="a-icon a-icon--24"></svg>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs col-xs-auto no-gutters-col">
                  <span class="ssNameText">bla1</span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="ssBlock">...</div> //outcome blabla2
   <div class="ssBlock">...</div> //outcome blabla3
   ...
</div>
```

my code:

```
items = driver.find_element_by_id('js-live').find_elements_by_class_name("ssBlock")

for item in items:
  print(item.find_element_by_xpath('//*/div/span[1]/div/div[2]/span').text)
```

Comment: Is xpath `//*/div/span[1]/div/div[2]/span` supposed to be relative to item variable? If yes, it should be `.//*/div/span[1]/div/div[2]/span` - with a dot in the beginning.

Comment: Yes, but with dot in the beginning it's throwing me error: Unable to locate element

Comment: Could you also add to your post content of the div element? It seems that xpath tries to get span element from the root of the document and it should be shortened to relative path from current div to child span. But without knowing the structure it's only a guess.

Comment: I understand, updated

Comment: Try to use `item.find_element_by_class_name('ssNameText').text` in the loop.

Comment: I tried, get same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete code using the example provided.

```
html_content = '''<div id="js-live">
   <div class="ssBlock">
      <div class="ssName">
         <span class="floatL withSvgIcon">
            <div class="row middle-xs">
               <div class="col-xs col-xs-auto">
                  <svg class="a-icon a-icon--24"></svg>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs col-xs-auto no-gutters-col">
                  <span class="ssNameText">bla1</span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </span>
      </div>
      <div class="ssBlock">
      <div class="ssName">
         <span class="floatL withSvgIcon">
            <div class="row middle-xs">
               <div class="col-xs col-xs-auto">
                  <svg class="a-icon a-icon--24"></svg>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs col-xs-auto no-gutters-col">
                  <span class="ssNameText">bla2</span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </span>
      </div>
      <div class="ssBlock">
      <div class="ssName">
         <span class="floatL withSvgIcon">
            <div class="row middle-xs">
               <div class="col-xs col-xs-auto">
                  <svg class="a-icon a-icon--24"></svg>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs col-xs-auto no-gutters-col">
                  <span class="ssNameText">bla3</span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>'''
   
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('<<PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER>>')
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))

items = driver.find_element_by_id('js-live').find_elements_by_class_name("ssBlock")

for item in items:
  print(item.find_element_by_class_name('ssNameText').text)
```

Output is

```
bla1
bla2
bla3
```

There is a possibility, that span elements are rendered dynamically. In that case one could wait till elements are present:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

for item in items:
  span = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ssNameText')))
  print(span.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, i tried both versions but im getting still same one result x times. I dont have idea why

Comment: Btw: I am trying to get that text from page elements so my `driver.get` looks like  `driver.get('someurl')`

Comment: Another common reason for such an error could be an iframe, inside of which the elements are located. Are there any frames on your webpage?

Comment: Well there are some iframes, but not wrapper around this html

Comment: Could you share the webpage URL?

Comment: This expression worked for me in the loop: span = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//span')

Comment: Well thank you so much, this is the final solution that work, but im still not sure why my code does not work